How should we tag questions about the TV series "3 Body Problem"?
At the moment there is a tag, 3-body-problem, being used for the Netflix adaption of The Three Body Problem.
We have an existing tag, the-three-body-problem, that is being used for the book series. The book series tag has the remembrance-of-earths-past franchise tag requirement.
Should questions about the Netflix adaptation (and all previous or subsequent adaptations for that matter) use the existing the-three-body-problem tag, with the franchise tag, and with the tv tag to specify the media?
Or, should we keep a separate tag, 3-body-problem, specifically for questions about the Netflix adaptation?

I have an opinion, but apparently everything I think about tags is wrong, so I'm not going to further waste my time...

Which TV series? There are four...

@DavidW I'd like to know your opinion. I can't promise I'll agree, but in general I disagree with any decisions being set in stone by the small subset of people who happened to be online when it was discussed.

@AndresF. - That is, alas. how democracy works. Sometimes you win by getting your supporters to show up

@Valorum yes, and like democracy, any vote should be possible to get overturned and changed! Especially minority votes.

Use Year-Suffixed Tags for Adaptations
To maintain consistency with established tagging conventions and avoid confusion between similarly named works, I recommend using year-suffixed tags for adaptations of "The Three-Body Problem" book or the "Remembrance of Earth's Past" book series.
For clarity, here's how the tags should be used:



Work
Tag




The Three-Body Problem (original book)
remembrance-of-earths-past


3 Body Problem (2024 Netflix TV series)
3-body-problem-2024


Three-Body (2023 Chinese TV series)
three-body-2023


The Three-Body Problem (2022 Chinese animated series)
the-three-body-problem-2022


Any other adaptation
[name-of-adaptation-release-year]



The remembrance-of-earths-past tag should encompass questions about any book in the book series, similar to how a-song-of-ice-and-fire and harry-potter are used for their respective book series. To avoid confusion with the adaptations, the existing the-three-body-problem tag (currently used for the book), the-dark-forest, and deaths-end tags should be merged into and made synonyms of remembrance-of-earths-past. This way, users typing "three-body" or the other book titles into the tag box will find the appropriate book series tag and not only the TV adaptation tags.
This approach aligns with the precedent set for the "A Song of Ice and Fire" book series. For instance, there is no ambiguity between the tag for the book "A Game of Thrones" and the TV series "Game of Thrones" because the a-song-of-ice-and-fire book series tag is used for questions about the "A Game of Thrones" book and not a-game-of-thrones.
For questions pertaining to elements from both the book series and an adaptation, both the remembrance-of-earths-past and the relevant adaptation tag should be used together, similar to how a-song-of-ice-and-fire and game-of-thrones are combined when appropriate.
Appending year suffixes aligns with our tagging conventions for works with similar names, e.g., dune-2021 and dune-2024 (search for "202", "200", or "199" at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags for more examples). This also keeps things simple and avoids needing the tv tag (like with game-of-thrones).
This approach provides a clear distinction between the original book series and its adaptations while maintaining consistency with established tagging conventions. It ensures that users can easily find and filter questions about their work of interest, whether it's the book series or a specific adaptation.


I generally agree with this, but I'm not so sure about "To avoid confusion with the adaptations, the existing the-three-body-problem tag (currently used for the book), should be merged into remembrance-of-earths-past." There are also tags for the other two books in the series, so this would introduce an inconsistency for the first book. To be consistent, either all or none of the individual book tags should be merged with (and probably made synonyms of) remembrance-of-earths-past. I don't think there'd be too much confusion with the adaptations as the latter's tags all have a year.

- Comment by Null
For consistency, all individual book tags in the "Remembrance of Earth's Past" series should be merged into and made synonyms of remembrance-of-earths-past.
Merging all individual book tags into the series tag would indeed avoid any inconsistency and potential confusion. It aligns with how we handle other popular book series like "A Song of Ice and Fire" and "Harry Potter," where the series tag encompasses all books in the series.

I like what you’ve laid out here, got my +1 :)

I generally agree with this, but I'm not so sure about "To avoid confusion with the adaptations, the existing the-three-body-problem tag (currently used for the book) should be merged into remembrance-of-earths-past." There are also tags for the other two books in the series, so this would introduce an inconsistency for the first book. To be consistent, either all or none of the individual book tags should be merged with (and probably made synonyms of) remembrance-of-earths-past. I don't think there'd be too much confusion with the adaptations as the latter's tags all have a year.

@Null I addressed your comment in my answer; see the current revision of the answer.

We treat Harry Potter and ASOIF differently precisely because they're different.

I usually like to have an overarching franchise tag that covers all of a series and its adaptations (e.g. we don't have separate tags for the LotR books and LotR films), but given the immense confusion over naming here, I think this answer makes sense. The only extra thing I'd suggest is adding a synonym to the book-series tag for the name of the first book, so that people typing "three-body" into the tag box will find that tag and not only the TV-adaptation tags.

@Randal'Thor "adding a synonym to the book-series tag for the name of the first book" I've incorporated your feedback into the answer.

I think this is now [meta-tag:status-completed]: I've renamed the existing tag [3-body-problem] to [tag:3-body-problem-2024] and merged/synonymised all three of the book tags [tag:the-dark-forest] and [tag:deaths-end] and [tag:the-three-body-problem] into the existing series tag [tag:remembrance-of-earths-past]. Please let me know if I've missed anything. Also, please check the tag wikis and excerpts on the surviving tags and rewrite if necessary. It should be very clear to casual users that the book series tag (a lesser-known name) covers the best-known title The Three-Body Problem.

Thanks @Randal'Thor!

I propose we do the following:
Questions asking about the book series would continue to be tagged as they are: with the relevant book tag and the required franchise tag remembrance-of-earths-past.
Questions about any of TV adaptations (both this current Netflix one, and the other three, including any remakes or future adaptations) would be tagged with both the the-three-body-problem tag and tv tag. And the usage guidance for the-three-body-problem would be updated to reflect, something like:

For questions about "The Three-Body Problem", a sci-fi novel by Chinese writer Liu CiXin that spawned several adaptations. For questions about the book series always use in conjunction with [remembrance-of-earths-past]. For questions about any of the subsequent adaptations use in conjunction with [tv].


A potential source of confusion here is that the tag does not accurately reflect the title of the Netflix TV show, which is "3 Body Problem" (same for the Chinese TV show adaptation). Also, the "3 Body Problem" TV show is an adaptation of the book series, not just the first novel "The Three-Body Problem" (elements from the second book, "The Dark Forest," have been incorporated into Season 1). This situation is analogous to the "Game of Thrones" TV series, which adapted the ASOIAF book series, not solely its first installment, "A Game of Thrones."

@galacticninja I see where you're coming from r.e. the GOT/ASOIAF naming. It does get a bit muddy when taking the adaptations into account (especially considering they draw from not just the first book).  My worry is having multiple tags that look similar will be confusing, it was fine with GOT because they are pretty distinct, but "3-body" vs "the-three-body" doesn't sit right with me (I don't think merging the franchise tag with the book tag is the right course of action). However, I do like your idea of adding some suffix to the tag, that might be the simplest solution.

Drawing from the precedent set by the tagging guidelines for game-of-thrones (TV series), a-song-of-ice-and-fire (book series), and harry-potter (book series), let's establish dedicated tags for the TV series and the book series.

For the Netflix adaptation: Continue using the existing tag 3-body-problem. This keeps things simple and avoids needing the tv tag (like with game-of-thrones), especially since the show's title, "3 Body Problem", is different from the book's title, "The Three-Body Problem", and the title of the other adaptations.
To aid users in finding the appropriate tag, consider making the following tags synonyms of 3-body-problem: 3-body-problem-tv-series and 3-body-problem-2024. Appending "tv-series" or year suffixes aligns with our tagging conventions for works with similar names, such as fallout-tv-series (no need for tv), dune-2021, and dune-2024.

For the book series: Continue using the existing tag remembrance-of-earths-past. Like with a-song-of-ice-and-fire and harry-potter, this tag should encompass questions about any book in the series. To avoid confusion with the similarly named Chinese animated series, the the-three-body-problem tag (currently used for the book) should be merged into remembrance-of-earths-past, which will remove it from any questions currently tagged with it.
This approach mirrors the tagging conventions for a-song-of-ice-and-fire and harry-potter, where there are no tags for specific books, preventing confusion with the TV and film adaptations. For instance, there is no ambiguity between the tag for the book "A Game of Thrones" and the TV series "Game of Thrones" because the a-song-of-ice-and-fire book series tag is used for questions about the "A Game of Thrones" book.

Combining book and TV tags: Only use remembrance-of-earths-past and 3-body-problem together when a question’s scope overlaps with elements from both the book series and the Netflix TV series.


This approach provides a clear distinction between the books and television adaptation while maintaining consistency with established tagging conventions.

I think having both 3-body-problem and the-three-body-problem is confusing... which one is which, and why is one spelled with a digit and the other with words? Wouldn't it be better to bake netflix or show into the tag?

@AndresF. You have a point there. I've edited my answer and added guidance more in line with the ASOIAF and Game of Thrones tagging conventions to avoid confusion.

@AndresF. I think adding a "netflix," "show," or "tv-series" suffix is a good idea, maybe even year suffixes. They should be synonyms pointing to the tag that represents the actual title of the TV series.

Year suffix would seem to be the cleanest option imo

3-body-problem and three-body-problem should be tag synonyms so people can use either.

@AlexRobinson I've added a separate answer suggesting year suffixes for all adaptations: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14083/7957
